# Late 70s/80s fantasy novel with interdimensional portals, an average man protagonist and an immortal beautiful warrior woman

Tags: story-identification, novel

I’ve been scouring my memory for the name of a book I read decades ago. I only remember fragments. Inter-dimensional portals, a female warrior who is immortal (and beautiful), an average man protagonist.

A Boris type cover with the scantily clad woman warrior on the cover... possibly with a Stonehenge type structure.

Comment: Hi there! This is a bit terse at the moment; could you take a look at [thse guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possibly the Morgaine Cycle by C.J. Cherryh. "Gate of Ivrel" is the first book,  published in 1976 so fits the timeframe provided. All other details - portals, female warrior, average man, cover with scantily clad woman warrior and structure - match too.

[image]

See if [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Morgaine_Stories) brings back memories.

Comment: I think this is it! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is right but Robert Heinlein's Glory Road fits the description.

Comment: Some more details on how this matches maybe? ;) (quotes, summary, Goodreads link etc...)

Comment: Star is beautiful, but not immortal.  They do travel between universes, but most often naked and using only a pentagram - no stonehenge style gates.  Oscar isn't exactly average, either.  He was selected for a special ability - he **always** knows where he is in relation to any place he has traveled.  This ability was needed to get through the labyrinth guarding the "egg."